How can I attach a second subpanel to this main?
This is my main panel with the meter. I have another subpanel that has been connected. It runs to a grain bin which is used once a year for a few days.
I have run my SER to my new barn. I have the panel setup and want to connect it to the main power.
I see how the electrician did the previous hookup with the lugs. My question is, how do I connect a second feed from this main box?


The new subpanel can be fed from a new circuit breaker, sized correctly to protect the new SER wires, just like the existing circuit breaker feeds the pole outlet below the meter panel.
The new circuit breaker also has to be sized according to an NEC load calculation, based on your existing subpanel and loads. What's left of this main panel's 200 amps, after subtracting the load calculation result, can be fed to your barn, considering the current limits imposed by the SER gauge, as well as stab current limits where you attach the new circuit breaker. The label on the door may show the stab limit, or you can consult the manufacturer's website & literature.
You'd probably also need another conduit to get the SER into this panel.

So, something like this: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Square-D-Homeline-200-Amp-2-Pole-Standard-Trip-Circuit-Breaker/3467883
Connect both legs to the circuit breaker and then attach the common similar to the way the other common in?
(I just picked the 200 amp for illustration; not including the calculations for the grain bin)

Probably more like a standard double breaker for the two power wires. The neutral would have to attach to the bus where the existing neutral wire (the black wire with the yellow stripe) attaches. If the SER neutral can fit in one of the holes in this panel's neutral bar without removing any strands of the neutral, then that would work. Or a compatible neutral lug might work.

Grounding!!!
The other answer is correct about the main connection - a breaker sized appropriately, using either 2 or 4 spaces, plus neutral to the neutral bar (and might need an extra lug for that).
But you have some serious potential issues with grounding.

The existing subpanel fed from the lugs at the bottom does not appear to have a ground wire. That may have been legitimate at the time, but has not generally been permitted for decades. In any case, your new subpanel does not get grandfathered and must have a ground wire - i.e., it must be a 4-wire feed. Sizes vary:

10 AWG copper or 8 AWG aluminum for up to 60A
8 AWG copper or 6 AWG aluminum for up to 100A
6 AWG copper or 4 AWG aluminum for up to 200A


This panel should have a ground wire going to (usually) two ground rods. This wire is typically a copper 6 AWG or 4 AWG wire (seems to be somewhat inspector/jurisdiction dependent, but 4 AWG is always good).

It is likely (but nothing is guaranteed) that your existing subpanel has a ground wire (good) going to ground rods or to an Ufer ground (good) - and that doesn't need to be removed as extra grounding is OK. But that it also has a neutral/ground bond (needs to be removed, but only after adding a ground wire...)

The critical parts are that to get up to code you need to (a) add a ground wire from subpanel to the now-main panel (easy if there is room (officially: conduit fill) in the conduit, not so easy if not) and (b) move any ground wires that are on the neutral bar in the subpanel to the ground bar (legal to be on the neutral bar in the main panel but not in a subpanel).


My hunch is:

This was originally used as only a service disconnect. As such, no ground wire/rods required to this panel and no ground wire to the main panel (what you have, properly, called a subpanel) and the panel fed by the lugs is the official main panel.
Sometime later, somebody decided to add a convenience receptacle at this location. But they didn't look at it or think about (or perhaps ignored) the grounding issues. Adding that convenience receptacle turned this box from a service disconnect into the main panel, with all associated effects on both this panel and the original main (now sub) panel.

Note that there are a number of things that can be at a panel of this type without turning it into the main panel for grounding purposes: surge protection, solar power and some other things. (See NEC 230.82 - thank you Harper for the reference.) But ordinary receptacles can't be connected to this panel without changing its status to main panel.

Prior to NEC 2008, a 3-wire subpanel feeder to an outbuilding was legal.  Even today, service wires  out the bottom of the panel are legit if a) the two main breakers (here and at the destination) are labeled per 230.85, and b) any loads in the main panel (e.g. here) are those allowed by 230.82.  Tapping a subpanel here is not allowed per 230.82 and thus makes this panel the main breaker/panel.
